# C++ Bitwise Shift using a File Pointer

Tags: c++, hex, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword, shift

I'm reading through someone else's code and can't quite understand how it's working. Here's the three lines of code. I want to know what the value of w3 is:

```
int w1 = fgetc(fp) & 0xFF;
int w2 = fgetc(fp) & 0xFF;
int w3 = w1 + (w2 << 8);
```

I understand that fgetc() returns a character from a FILE* fp, but I'm getting confused when he's using the & operator on a character with the value 0xFF. Then using the bitwise shift operator on w2 and adding it to w1. I'm not sure if I should be expected a character or an integer. This is a code snippet from a program that reads binary data from a file, generates UV coordinates as output. But I'm less concerned with that, and more concerned with how the above code works.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: First off, `fgetc()` returns a `int`, not a char. Second, he's clearing all but the low 8-bit of the returned `int` for both values, then slipping the second 8-bit value `w2` into bits 8-15 of the low 16 bits (0..15) of `w3`. When done he'll have (assuming 32bit ints) `0x0000w2w1` as the value in `w3` More important, however, if `fp` is at EOF, and `EOF` is returned on either `fgetc()` this could get ugly quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `& 0xff` ensures that the result is unsigned. Then, `w1 + (w2 << 8)` makes a 16-bit integer from the two bytes. In effect, this code snippet is reading in a little-endian two-byte integer.

Answer (score 1):

What this `int w1 = fgetc(fp) & 0xFF;` does is to mask the received `int` into a single byte. (`fgetc()` returns an `int` after all)

What this `w1 + (w2 << 8);` does is to combine both bytes in to a single `int`. Probably trying to deserialize a previously serialized integer. (Not the best way of doing it if endianness is an issue)

Comment: Well, if the integer is specified to be stored in little-endian format, this is the best way.

Comment: True that, if you are reading and writing on the same platform.

Comment: @nneonneo The most portable way would be to read 2 bytes and convert with htonl. Depends on your definition of "best" I guess.